# Can you organize Git Repos into folders?

Tags: git, azure-repos

My team is currently using Team Foundation Server with the TFSVC for version control. I'm wanting us to move over to using Git within TFS. I had the TFS team setup Git for our team. However, I would like to organize our projects into folders if possible. Example might be a folder for HR and one for Finance and one for Training, etc. Then I would have a project Repo under those folders depending on the what it's for. Right now we have about 170 projects which is why I would like to organize them into folders to help from scrolling forever.

I reached out to my TFS team about this but I haven't received a response so I don't know if it's not possible, if they don't know how to do it, or if I don't have permission.

I've watched some online Videos but all of the info I've found deals with doing that in GitHub, which we aren't using.

If you look at my screen shot you can see that I created some sub folders but I can't figure out how to create a repo in those folders. I see Git repositories which is outside of those folders. I created a TestRepo but again it's not under a folder.

Is it possible to use folders to organize our repositories? If I add a new repository, I don't seem to have a way to put it in a sub folder.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to organize Git repositories into subfolders.

In the new UI introduced with Azure DevOps Server 2019 (formerly Team Foundation Server), the repo picker has been reduced to an auto-filtering search box:

[image]

This is the better solution over folders.

Comment: Bummer...I'm betting my manager is going to give me push back for moving to Git over that but I'm going to try to keep them moving over to Git. That explains why I've never heard anything back from our TFS team about it.

Comment: Maybe it's a nice way to get them to migrate to Azure DevOps or upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019.

Comment: do you know if you I can create subfolders for organizing in GitHub?

Comment: No, GitHub also uses a quick-filter system. When you have lots of repos, folders aren't your best friend. Tagging, quick-filter and search are.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, I'm just going to have to change their mindset. Old habits are hard to break.

Comment: Except that there is no tagging in Azure Devops. Users shouldn't have to know what prefix to type to access a repo.

Comment: The tagging remark was meant as a broader approach. Work item tagging, tags on builds etc. If you have feedback on the product, please use the send feedback feature. -1 on this answer won't change things.

Comment: You can always write an extension to implement your desired functionality.

Comment: Downvoting because you don't like the answer isn't helpful. While I don't necessarily agree that "This is a better solution over folders.", jessehouwing did answer the question I had, which is what stackoverflow is ultimately about.