# Is it possible to group git repositories into subfolders under AzureDevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

Recently, we migrated from our TFVC to git repository. I would like to decouple a few of our solutions into separate git repositories. Is it possible somehow to group these newly created repos under some kind of subfolder on AzureDevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to group git repositories into subfolders under AzureDevOps?

The answer is yes.

The most **important** thing before starting is to backup your current project/solutions.

I created a simple example to demonstrate how to accomplish it.

I created a repo with three solutions (`Solution1`, `Solution2`, `Solution3`)in it:

[image]

Add three subfolders (`Subfolder1`, `Subfolder2`, `Subfolder3`)in this repo via Azure devops web page:

[image]

Now, open our Visual Studio locally, connect to this repo. And move the `solution1` to the `subfolder1` in the file explorer:

[image]

Then, push this change to the repo:

[image]

Now, the `solution1` moved to the `subfolder1`.

**Update:**

> But basically my question was if there is possible to create
> **subfolders for some git repositories**, not a subfolders inside git
> repository

I think it is impossible to create **subfolders for some git repositories**. You need to create other repo in the project. When you have lots of repos, folders aren't your best friend. Tagging, quick-filter and search are.

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55599509/can-you-organize-git-repos-into-folders) for some details.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But basically my question was if there is possible to create subfolders for some git repositories, not a subfolders inside git repository :)

Comment: @Matthew, Sorry for not understanding your question correctly. But I think it is impossible to create subfolders for some git repositories. You could check my updated answer for some more details.

Comment: No worries. I checked this thread before but still have a liitle bit hope this is possible somehow (TFS memories :)) Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Matthew, You are always welcome! Have a nice day! :)